How to fix server to support range requests?
I have a laravel project and i want to show videos to my users but the videos always start from the beginning when the progress bar is clicked.
I searched and found out that the problem is that the server doesn't properly support range requests.
Also i'm using xampp and videojs.
Could somebody please tell how to fix it?
